# NetBeans - Two projects - one cannot find file to include (C++)

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have created two projects in `NetBeans 7.4`. First one is Dynamic library. The second one is an application which uses library from the first project.
I have added it in properties of second project (*Properties -> Linker -> Libraries -> Add project*).
Both projects use SDL library. When I build only the first one, build is always finished successfully. When I build the second project, I receive error from my library (which is second project):

> Fatal error: SDL.h: File doesn't exists

I have attached SDL in Linker properties before compilation.

I suspect that I have to do something in Linker or Compiler configuration but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have set-up the correct include directories in your second project. Look at the "code assistance" section in the compiler properties.

Comment: I'm sure that I did it properly.